# How to detect top is reached on inverted react-native flat list

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

am designing a chat screen, in which the data is shown from bottom . to top. once the top is reached need to do pagination API call. I have used a flat list for showing the data with the inverted prop. once I reach the top of the list I have to make another call.

I have tried to find scroll height but that is also not coming :(

```
<FlatList
          ref={nameRef}
          data={messages}
          renderItem={({ item }) => renderData(item)}
          inverted
          onScroll={(e) => handleScroll(e)}
        />
```

I need to do an API call once it reached the top of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onEndReached` prop to determine the top like below:

```
<FlatList
      ref={nameRef}
      data={messages}
      renderItem={({item}) => renderData(item)}
      inverted
      onEndReached={this.handlePagination}
    />
```

Comment: it gets called initially once it gets inverted

Comment: Use `onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}` and run it.